# Submitting multiple values in a web form using Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, ruby-on-rails-4

Users can submit multiple message numbers in a web form:

```
<input type="text" name="message"/>
```

But when I read `params[:message]` in a rails controller, I only get the first message number. Is there a way to get an array of message numbers?

I know I could have something like the following:

```
<input type="text" name="message1"/>
<input type="text" name="message2"/>
<input type="text" name="message3"/>
```

But it would be so much nicer and easier if I could simply get an array of numbers.

Answer (score 3):

Figured it out, noticed a section in the [Ruby on Rails guide about Understanding Parameter Naming Conventions](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.13/form_helpers.html#understanding-parameter-naming-conventions) which described what to do:

```
<input type="text" name="message[]"/>
```